# como le pongo otro where o como puedo hacer otro filtro en mi consulta

Tags: php, mysql

estoy intentando hacer dos where en la misma consulta pero no se como hacerlo quisiera que mi consulta pudiera filtrar 1 si existe un cupon 2 si el cupon aun es vigente hasta aca solo me busca el cupon y si existe me dice cupon valido y tengo un problema mas no se como convertir mi fecha a formato tipo string me lo pasa asi 2020-08-13

```
<?php 

define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_SERVER_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_SERVER_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'prueba');

$connexion = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);



sleep(1);
if (isset($_POST)) {

    $cupon = (string)$_POST['cupon'];
    $precios_id = (string)$_POST['precios_id'];
  
    
    
    $result = $connexion->query(
        'SELECT * FROM precios WHERE cupon = "'.strtolower($cupon).'"'
    );
    
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Enhorabuena!</strong> Cupon valido. '.$cupon.' '.$precios_id.'<a class="btn" href="https://pagina.com/">dd</a>
    </div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Oh no!</strong> Cupon invalido.</div>';
    }
}
```

intente hacer esto pero sigue sin funcionar intente pasar la fecha en una variable llamara vigencia_fin que es la que estoy usando y con la que quiero hacer referencia si mi cupon ya expiro mi tabla se llama precios y tiene los campos id, cupon, precio, vigencia_inicio, vigencia_fin

```
$connexion = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);



sleep(1);
if (isset($_POST)) {

    
           setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_MX.UTF-8');
           $vigencia_fin = strftime("%d %b %Y", strtotime('.$vigencia_fin.'));
           .$vigencia_fin. = $vigencia_fin;
      

    $cupon = (string)$_POST['cupon'];
    $id_evento = (string)$_POST['id_evento'];
    $fecha_actual = date("Y-m-d");
    $newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha_actual));
    $x = $newDate;

    
    $result = $connexion->query(
        'SELECT * FROM precios WHERE cupon = "'.$cupon.' " '
    );
        if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              $precio=$row["precios_id"];
              $preciomx=$row["preciomx"]; 
              $preciousd=$row["preciousd"];
              $descripcion=$row["descripcion"];
               $vigencia_fin=$row["vigencia_fin"];
        echo '<div class="alert " style="margin-top: 1%">
 '.$vigencia_fin.'
```

Comment: Aquí no hay Laravel por algún lado, por eso edité y quité la etiqueta

Comment: SELECT * FROM precios WHERE cupon = "'.$cupon.' and Vigencia_fin Between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31'

Answer (score 0):

Mira te recomiento que tu between lo hagas usando

```
str_to_date('2020-08-13', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: este como seria bueno algun ejemplo